# Кнопки в боте DIscord

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Помогите пожалуйста добавить кнопки под сообщением в дискорд - боте.
Убедительная просьба: сделать это без class, я классы совсем не понимаю.
Примерный уровень моих знаний в фреймворке:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg=None):
    if "Premium" not in [r.name for r in ctx.author.roles]:
        await ctx.invoke(border, arg = 'У вас нет доступа к этой команде.\nДля этого нужна роль "Premium".')
await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/ui_elements.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8